# Sorting the bars in a bar chart with dc.js

Tags: sorting, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to **dc.js** and **d3.js**. I have created a **bar chart** along with pie charts and a line chart with dc.js.

Now, in the bar chart I want to **sort the bars** based on the value that each bar represents. (For example, by clicking a button.) Is this possible with dc.js?

Note that I have designed my bar chart such that the X-axis represents geographic locations and the Y-axis is scaling on some value.

Answer (score 7):

Could you show us some code ?

In the past I have done that this way for a row chart :

```
var topRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-top-dest");

topRowChart
.height(400)
.width(400)
.dimension(destination, "destination")
.group(calls,"calls")
.ordering(function(t){return t.calls;})
.label(function(d){ return d.key + " : " + d.value + " calls" ;})
.cap(10);
```

The important bits are :

```
.ordering(function(t){return t.calls;})
.cap(10);
```

You have to pass a function to **ordering()** that returns the dimension/group that will be used for sorting.

Surprisingly removing **cap()** cancels the sorting.

Comment: Hi when I try to add ordering function it throws error ".ordering() is not a function" . In DC.js there is function for ordering. currently using version- 1.6.0 . What could be the mistake ??

Comment: Sorry. it throws error for Cap function. As its a row chart function. But for bar chart sorting what could be used. ? I have sorted based on domain var domain = [];

barchartlocation.top(Infinity).forEach(function(d) {
   domain[domain.length] = d.key;
})

Comment: dc.js Stable (v1.6.0) dosen't have ordering(). But Master(v2.0.0-dev) has ordering. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#orderingorderfunction

Comment: Note that there is [a bug](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/766) in **dc.js** in sorting the bars in a **bar chart**, at least through **2.0.0-beta.5**. I have had success with **2.0.0-beta.12**.